ButtonStyle makeBody ViewBuilder triggers PreferenceKey reduce
I have a problem with ButtonStyle's function makeBody triggers PreferenceKey reduce function, if I have switch or if statement inside makeBody.
I have a code below:
struct TestPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    
    static var defaultValue: Int = 0

    static func reduce(value: inout Int, nextValue: () -> Int) {

        print("reduce value:", value)
        print("reduce nextValue:", nextValue())

        value = nextValue()
    }
}

struct TestButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {

    enum `Type` {
        case a
        case b
    }

    let type: `Type`

    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        switch type {
        case .a:
            configuration.label
        case .b:
            configuration.label
        }
    }
}

struct ButtonView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button {

        } label: {
            Text("Button")
        }
        .buttonStyle(TestButtonStyle(type: .a))
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ButtonView()
            ButtonView()
        }
        .onPreferenceChange(TestPreferenceKey.self) { value in
            print("value:", value)
        }
    }
}

And I have the next prints in log:
reduce value: 0
reduce nextValue: 0
value: 0

As I understand how PreferenceKey works, I should have nothing printed out.
And it works so, if I call different function from ButtonStyle's makeBody:
struct TestButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {

    enum `Type` {
        case a
        case b
    }

    let type: `Type`

    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        switcher(configuration: configuration)
    }

    func switcher(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        switch type {
        case .a:
            configuration.label
        case .b:
            configuration.label
        }
    }
}

Now, I have nothing printed out.
But, if I add @ViewBuilder wrapper to switcher function, I have printed out again:
...
    @ViewBuilder
    func switcher(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        switch type {
        case .a:
            configuration.label
        case .b:
            configuration.label
        }
    }

reduce value: 0
reduce nextValue: 0
value: 0

Is it expected behavior with ViewBuilder? Or is it a bug?
Is it always necessary to do such a traversal with an additional function?
If anyone knows the answer, it would be much appreciated! I would also be grateful for useful links on the topic!
UDP:
If I add .preference for one of Views, I get a wrong result of TestPreferenceKey value:
...
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ButtonView()
            .preference(
                key: TestPreferenceKey.self,
                value: 3
            )
        ButtonView()
    }
    .onPreferenceChange(TestPreferenceKey.self) { value in
            print("value:", value)
    }
}

Result is:
reduce value: 3
reduce nextValue: 0
value: 0

Although the TestPreferenceKey value should be 3.
Of course, without @ViewBuilder on switcher TestPreferenceKey value is right - 3
Printed out:
value: 3


The purpose of reduce is for SwiftUI to combine the preference values of sibling views.

This method receives its values in view-tree order. Conceptually, this combines the preference value from one tree with that of its next sibling.

It is not documented whether reduce will be called in any particular case, so you should not make assumptions about that. If SwiftUI feels the need to "combine the preference value from one tree with that of its next sibling", then reduce can be called.
In your example, reduce is called because SwiftUI tries to combine the preference value of the first ButtonView with that of the second ButtonView, to produce a combined preference value for the VStack in which they are located. SwiftUI is not guaranteed to do this, though. As you have experienced, removing @ViewBuilder causes reduce to not be called. SwiftUI "sees" that the second ButtonView doesn't have a preference modifier, and just takes the preference value of the first ButtonView.
This means that your implementation of reduce should not produce a different result depending on whether it is called for a view without a preference value. i.e. the following two VStacks should have the same combined preference value:
VStack {
    Text("Foo")
        .preference(
            key: TestPreferenceKey.self,
            value: 3
        )
    Text("Bar") // reduce is **not** called to combine this with 3
}
VStack {
    Text("Foo")
        .preference(
            key: TestPreferenceKey.self,
            value: 3
        )
    Text("Bar")
        .preference(
            key: TestPreferenceKey.self,
            value: 0
        ) // reduce **is** called to combine this with 3
}

In fact, the documentation for defaultValue states:

Views that have no explicit value for the key produce this default value. Combining child views may remove an implicit value produced by using the default. This means that reduce(value: &x, nextValue: {defaultValue}) shouldn’t change the meaning of x.

This is clearly not true for your implementation of reduce, so your implementation is incorrect.
An implementation that does fulfill this requirement is:
struct TestPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    
    static var defaultValue: Int? = nil

    static func reduce(value: inout Int?, nextValue: () -> Int?) {
        if let next = nextValue() {
            value = next
        }
    }
}

This implementation uses nil as an indication that the preference is not set, and takes the last (in view tree order) preference that is not nil.
Side Note: the difference that @ViewBuilder makes here is it turns the if statement into a _ConditionalContent view. Presumably because of some implementation detail, SwiftUI treats this differently. I would not be surprised if this behaviour changes in the future.

I understand all theory working that you describe. You also type in an example "reduce is not called to combine this with 3" and "VStacks should have the same combined preference value". But in my case in the last example I set preferenceKey value 3 to the first view and reduce was called and my VStack has a value 0 now (it's printed out in log "value: 0"), and it's not expected result. It's behavior when I have a ViewBuilder, without it, reduce not called and VStack value is trues - 3

@Anastasiia I’m saying that this is because you did not implement reduce correctly. SwiftUI behaving differently because your view hierarchy is slightly different is totally expected, and your implementation of reduce should account for that. reduce(value: &x, nextValue: {defaultValue}) should not change x.

@Anastasiia I have edited the answer to include an example of a correct implementation.
